# How to deploy a site like a installation package using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, installation

I am developing a e-commerice website using PHP & MYSQL.

I would like to make that site in to installation package.

So that it will be easy for every one to handle.

How can this be done?

any help will be thankful and grateful.

thanks in advance...

Comment: well what do yo exactly do you want to do? have a look at joomla and wordpress

Comment: i already did what you have mentioned. But i don't know how to start it.. that's why i need a proper guidance or manual. That's why i posted this question here.

Answer (score 1):

Well my suggestion would be to look at similar open source ecommerce apps such as opencart, prestashop, tomatocart, oscommerce and see how they have done the self installation.

Generally, the way it works is installation steps, setup the configure file which consists of data gathered from the user for database connection, website url, username, password, store name etc. Once the configure file is done and database connection is tested, the installation script then sets up the database structure and inputs any dummy data you may have.